# Unmet dependencies when updating PHP 5.4.8 to 5.4.15 using dotdeb on debian

Tags: php5, aptitude, dotdeb

I'm not quite sure how to act here. I installed php5 as dotdeb package. I'm on **debian squeeze 686**. Now I try to update from 5.4.8 to 5.4.15 and get the following output after running `aptitude install php5`:

```
 aptitude install php5
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-php5{ab} lsof{a}
The following packages will be upgraded:
  php5 php5-common
2 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 95 not upgraded.
Need to get 3529 kB of archives. After unpacking 9138 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libapache2-mod-php5filter: Depends: php5-common (= 5.4.8-1~dotdeb.0) but 5.4.15-1~dotdeb.1 is to be installed.
                             Conflicts: libapache2-mod-php5 but 5.4.15-1~dotdeb.1 is to be installed.
  php5-xdebug: Depends: php5-common (= 5.4.8-1~dotdeb.0) but 5.4.15-1~dotdeb.1 is to be installed.
  php5-gd: Depends: php5-common (= 5.4.8-1~dotdeb.0) but 5.4.15-1~dotdeb.1 is to be installed.
  php5-mcrypt: Depends: php5-common (= 5.4.8-1~dotdeb.0) but 5.4.15-1~dotdeb.1 is to be installed.
  php5-mysql: Depends: php5-common (= 5.4.8-1~dotdeb.0) but 5.4.15-1~dotdeb.1 is to be installed.
  php5-cli: Depends: php5-common (= 5.4.8-1~dotdeb.0) but 5.4.15-1~dotdeb.1 is to be installed.
  libapache2-mod-php5: Conflicts: libapache2-mod-php5filter but 5.4.8-1~dotdeb.0 is installed and it is kept back.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Remove the following packages:
1)      libapache2-mod-php5filter
2)      php-pear
3)      php5-cli
4)      php5-gd
5)      php5-mcrypt
6)      php5-mysql
7)      php5-xdebug
8)      phpmyadmin

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:
9)      libapache2-mod-php5 recommends php5-cli
10)     phpmyadmin recommends php5-gd
```

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` (`sources.list.d` is empty):

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian squeeze main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian-security squeeze/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all

deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54 all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54 all
```

`dpkg -l ‘php*’ | grep ‘^.i’` gives me this:

```
ii php-pear 5.3.3-7+squeeze1 PEAR – PHP Extension and Application Repository
ii php5 5.4.8-1~dotdeb.0 server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii php5-cli 5.4.8-1~dotdeb.0 command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
ii php5-common 5.4.8-1~dotdeb.0 Common files for packages built from the php5 source
ii php5-gd 5.4.8-1~dotdeb.0 GD module for php5
ii php5-mcrypt 5.4.8-1~dotdeb.0 MCrypt module for php5
ii php5-mysql 5.4.8-1~dotdeb.0 MySQL module for php5
ii php5-xdebug 5.4.8-1~dotdeb.0 xdebug module for php5
ii phpmyadmin 4:3.3.7-5 MySQL web administration tool
```

So Is it safe to continue here? Of course I want the packages to work after the update but it seems they will be broken afterwards, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Well.. instead of just updating php5 I ran

```
aptitude full-upgrade
```

which went through and updated php5 to the latest version as well. I don't have a clue why that worked, though.

Comment: Most likely APT wasn't automatically updating the dependencies properly. Doing that updated those packages too.

Answer (score 0):

> So Is it safe to continue here?

No, if you continue, some php5 packages will be uninstalled. This seems to be a problem with the mirror. Probably it will be resolved soon, then just run `apt-get update` and try again. If not, please post your Debian version, architecture and sources.list.